# “The site uses SSL, but Google Chrome has detected insecure content on the page.”

Tags: ssl

I have just set up SSL on my site https://helloacm.com   and the home page is OK but this URL https://helloacm.com/milestones/  browsing in Chrome shows “The site uses SSL, but Google Chrome has detected insecure content on the page.”

I have googled a lot and almost every article says that I should change all http to https for images, css and links.. but I have viewed the source code and found out there are not references to http://helloacm.com  any more.. so I don't get it , why this url still shows error.

Comment: Look at the console. It'll show things that weren't loaded over SSL.

Comment: Probabbly one of your ads didn't play nicely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The site uses SSL, but Google Chrome has detected insecure content on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599631/the-site-uses-ssl-but-google-chrome-has-detected-insecure-content-on-the-page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in the console. For me, it says:

> - Mixed Content: The page at 'https://helloacm.com/milestones/' was loaded over HTTPS, but contains a form whose 'action' attribute is
>     'http://www.google.co.uk/'. This form should not submit data to
>     insecure endpoints.
> - Mixed Content: The page at 'https://helloacm.com/milestones/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>     'http://uploadbeta.com/_s/upload/2014/09/04/1137292dd6fbe2b75f1373cb0e3c7a1c.jpg.jpg'.
>     This content should also be served over HTTPS.
> - Mixed Content: The page at 'https://helloacm.com/milestones/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>     'http://uploadbeta.com/_s/upload/2014/09/26/eb174fb4bab9f8cba5ef25fb0321234f.jpg'.
>     This content should also be served over HTTPS.
> - Mixed Content: The page at 'https://helloacm.com/milestones/' was loaded over HTTPS, but contains a form whose 'action' attribute is
>     'http://www.google.com/'. This form should not submit data to insecure
>     endpoints.

Simply fix the errors here, and that warning will go away. Also, regarding the second error: why are you requesting a `.jpg.jpg`? For me that simply reduces the quality. Just change that to a `.jpg`.

Comment: thanks.. i don't get it... the uploadbeta.com domain is hosted on the same VPS, but different domain.. why should I make it HTTPS?

Comment: @DoctorLai Because if you don't make it SSL, then someone could still change what your website looks like, making it pointless to use SSL? Because that's simply *what it tells you to do?*

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to throw in another answer here for those of you who have tried everything and are still getting this error message.

With some hosts, like WP Engine, where you have yourwebsite.com but then another version of your site like yourinstall.wpengine.com (MediaTemple has something like this, and probably lots of other hosts), and especially if you built / developed the site at that temporary URL, and then set things up to forward the install to your actual URL...do a check in your database, because depending on how the forwarding works at the server level, you might see https://yourwebsite.com/my-image.png and be baffled, but in the database the actual image being served is still from the temporary domain.

Had me baffled forever!

Answer (score -1):

You must set the "$config_location_base" as http**s**://yoursite.com  directive in your config.