# Heroku and Nodejs: How to server static files(css and js over) https connection?

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

When I run my app locally(on localhost) everything goes as expected, but when I create the git and publish it to heroku and access it by browser I see only the HTML file and css and js are not loaded. console says:

that html was loaded over https and requesed the static files that are 'insecure script' and were blocked!

which means that it cannot serve static files over https. Supposing I have a pretty basic node and epxress setup what could be wrong, or what should I change?

Comment: That error [probably suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599631/the-site-uses-ssl-but-google-chrome-has-detected-insecure-content-on-the-page) the static files are served over HTTP, opposing the HTTPS used for the page. Are any static files being referenced by a full URL -- e.g. `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"`?

Comment: they are not referenced by full URL. How should I serve them iwht http? By using full URL?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski they are not referenced by full URL. How should I serve them iwht http? By using full URL?